# Display image at 50% of its "native" size

Tags: css

I'm putting an `img` tag in a document without knowing the width/height of the corresponding image:

```
<img src="/myimage.png" />
```

I want to use CSS to scale the image to exactly half of its "native" size (the size of the underlying image). I can't figure out how to do this.

- Using `width: 50%` would size relative to the containing block, not the image.
- I can't size to a specific pixel width because I don't know the image size.
- Since I only need to support WebKit, I've tried using a transform:

  ```
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  ```

  This adjusts the image nicely, but doesn't resize the size of the image element itself.
- @Radagaisus suggests using Javascript, which is a good fallback. However this is on an ultra lightweight mobile page so I can't use jQuery, and dealing with all the onload() handlers manually would be a pain.

As a postscript: why I am doing this? Because I need to handle the Retina display. I can detect it using `devicePixelRatio` and fill in larger (2x) images, but I need to scale them down to 50% to look correct on the display.

Comment: What if you use both `-webkit-transform: scale(0.5);` and `width: 50%;`?

Comment: @ZachRattner No, unfortunately that still sizes to half the containing block.

Comment: @Radagaisus That's my fallback, but this is an ultra-lightweight mobile page so I can't use jQuery, and dealing with all the onload handlers manually is a real pain.

Comment: If it's meant to be ultra lightweight, why scale images down with CSS instead of reduce their actual size? Are you "zooming them in" to full size at some point?

Comment: @WesleyMurch Good point. I omitted the reason: this is for an iPhone 4 Retina display. I can detect it using devicePixelRatio, then fill in bigger images, but now I need to scale them down.

Comment: I'm almost dying to know whether or not there's a good way to do this in other browsers as well.

Comment: Due to your constraint (lightweight load clientside), I think it would be advisable to implement detection at first session hit, and do all image resize serverside. Resizing an image to 50% of its original dimentions would roughly mean 1/4 of data transferred. Oh, and sorry for the necro. =/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's somewhat weird, but it seems that Webkit, at least in newest stable version of Chrome, supports Microsoft's `zoom` property. The good news is that its behaviour is closer to what you want.

Unfortunately DOM `clientWidth` and similar properties still return the original values as if the image was not resized.

```js
// hack: wait a moment for img to load
setTimeout(function() {
   var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
   document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = "clientWidth, clientHeight = " + img.clientWidth + ", " +
      img.clientHeight;
}, 1000);
```

```css
img {
  zoom: 50%;
}
/* -- not important below -- */
#t {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #F88;
}
#s {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #8F8;
}
```

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
<div id="s">div with explicit size for comparison 200px by 150px</div>
<div id="t">div with explicit size for comparison 400px by 300px</div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, perfect. A momentary rant: I can't **believe** that CSS doesn't have a way to do this easily. Ugh.

Comment: +1 you learn something random every day ;) I'd no idea other browsers would ever adopt `zoom`... v. strange.

Comment: Your demo is now missing, please post relevant answer code directly in your answer for posterity.

Comment: This is not supported in _any_ version of Firefox. This should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: Seconded: http://caniuse.com/#search=zoom, why is this accepted? I guess doing them as backgrounds is the only way really?

Comment: Why haven't you used document ready function rather than timeout hack?

Comment: Zoom is not an acceptable answer because it doesn't work in Firefox (over 10% browser share) and it is non-standard (see description of property on Caniuse.com).

Answer (score 88):

The zoom property sounds as though it's perfect for Adam Ernst as it suits his target device. However, for those who need a solution to this and have to support as many devices as possible you can do the following:

```
<img src="..." onload="this.width/=2;this.onload=null;" />
```

The reason for the `this.onload=null` addition is to avoid older browsers that sometimes trigger the load event twice *(which means you can end up with quater-sized images)*. If you aren't worried about that though you could write:

```
<img src="..." onload="this.width/=2;" />
```

Which is quite succinct.

Comment: Wish I could up-vote more! I'm trying to get dynamic images (which never get written to disk) resized for Retina - this was the perfect solution. Plus I like that it doesn't use any CSS hacks...

Comment: @David, I wouldn't think that using JS is any better than CSS "hacks".

Comment: `this.width*=0.5` is more efficient, granted the difference is negliable but it's nice to get into the habit!

Comment: @RoryPicko92 Fair point for some compilers. If you really want to get into optimisations though `this.width>>=1` would be faster still (less accurate if you need those half pixels!!), however, succinctness and readability should win out over micro-optimisations imo.

Comment: @pebbl awesome way to do it.

Comment: Awesome. Better than the accepted CSS solution IMO. Thanks pebbl.

Comment: Firefox 38 was coming up with strange results, but when I changed `this.width` to `this.naturalWidth`, it worked.

Comment: @Soheil — What browser are you using, and how are you implementing? Because all my tests work with data-urls — https://jsfiddle.net/Xadvz/3068/

Comment: @rorypicko No, it's not good to get into the habit of preoptimizing over readability.

Answer (score 28):

The following code works for me:

```
.half {
    -moz-transform:scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.5);
    transform:scale(0.5);
}

<img class="half" src="images/myimage.png">
```

Comment: See my third bullet point. This resizes the image itself, but if you put it in the flow of some text, there will be whitespace all around the image since the element itself is still full-size.

Comment: test of your code: http://50.17.204.145/random-stuff/scale-image.php (best solution yet, but it still have the full image area around it)

Answer (score 7):

Using the `x` descriptor of the `srcset` attribute can be a simple solution.

```html
<!-- Original image -->
<img src="https://fr.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia.png" />

<!-- With a 80% size reduction (1/0.8=1.25) -->
<img srcset="https://fr.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia.png 1.25x" />

<!-- With a 50% size reduction (1/0.5=2) -->
<img srcset="https://fr.wikipedia.org/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia.png 2x" />
```

Currently supported by all browsers except IE. ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/srcset))

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset)

Answer (score 3):

Set the image to be the background of a div, then set the background size to be half the width of the image.

```
<div class="myimage"></div>
```

Then in your css, if your image is 300px x 200px:

```
.myimage {
    background: url('images/myimage.png') no-repeat;
    background-size:150px;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: OP said "I can't size to a specific pixel width because I don't know the image size." If you knew the size you could set half the width directly to the <img>, no need for a background.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
max-width: 0.5em;
```

and then experiment with the font-size?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -9):

This should work:

```
img {
    max-width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: It will take 50% width of wrapper block