# setting the 50% of original picture width and height using css

Tags: css, image, image-processing

is there any way of setting the 50% of original picture width and height using css? 
for example i have this code:

```
    <img src="http://content.captive-portal.com/files/ign/movie-news/content/2b.jpg">
```

I don't specify any width and height in html, but I want it to be 50% of the original height and width. Can I use CSS to do that?

this doesn't work:

```
img{width:50%; height:50%}
```

Is there any way to overcome this?
Thanks

Comment: The css style you apply should work. Can you post more details?

Comment: Setting 50% width will make the image 50% as wide as its container. You need to know the original size.

Comment: This can only be done client-side with JavaScript.

Comment: I see. That's what I thought.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397049/css-image-resize-percentage-of-itself

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699621/display-image-at-50-of-its-native-size

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can scale the image as described here:
[CSS image resize percentage of itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397049/css-image-resize-percentage-of-itself)

```
img {-webkit-transform: scale(0.5); /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
 -moz-transform: scale(0.5); /* FF3.5+ */
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5); /* IE9 */
   -o-transform: scale(0.5); /* Opera 10.5+ */
      transform: scale(0.5);
         /* IE6–IE9 */
         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.9999619230641713, M12=-0.008726535498373935, M21=0.008726535498373935, M22=0.9999619230641713,SizingMethod='auto expand');}​
```

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my comment. Setting `width: 50%` in CSS will only set the image's width to 50% of its containing element.

You will need to achieve this using JavaScript. jQuery makes it quite straightforward, for example:

```
$('img').each(function() {  
    var the_width = $(this).width(),
        new_width = Math.round(the_width / 2);
    $(this).width(new_width);
});
```

Comment: Just why do you have to force JQuery!

Comment: Why not? It is becoming the industry standard, and when you compare the code required for this (trivial) procedure, it makes sense to harness the power of jQuery. Of course, there's no point including an entire library for one task, but I highly suspect that the OP is already using it (I mean, who isn't)...

Answer (score 3):

Can be solved inline:

```
<img src="..." onload="this.width*=0.5"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS...
myIMG{zoom:50%;}

inline-CSS

```
    <IMG STYLE="zoom:50%;" SRC="...">
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?