# ASP.NET List population

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am loading images onto a page. Actually, in response to a selection change in a DropDownList. When the user makes a selection, I use the text from the selected item to get an image from a virtual folder.

And that works just fine. I resize the image to 30% height and width.

BUT when I use asp:hyperlink instead of the image, and I the control like this:

```
string str = ImageList1.SelectedItem.Text; 
ImageFromList.ImageUrl = "~/Content/Images/SubDir/" + str + " width=30% height=30%" ;
ImageFromList.ResolveUrl("~/Content/Images/SubDir/" + str);
ImageFromList.NavigateUrl = "/Content/Images/SubDir/" + str;
```

this gets reformtted to look like:

```
style="display:inline-block;height:30%;width:30%;"
```

which doesn't seem to display the image at 30% size.

Comment: you're making the image 30% of it's container, which is not what you want.  [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699621/display-image-at-50-of-its-native-size) a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

why do you put your height and width inside your url path? what about CssClass property? (msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string str = ImageList1.SelectedItem.Text; 
ImageFromList.ImageUrl = "~/Content/Images/SubDir/" + str;
ImageFromList.CssClass = "yourCssClass"; // yourCssClass = your class with width and height
ImageFromList.ResolveUrl("~/Content/Images/SubDir/" + str);
ImageFromList.NavigateUrl = "/Content/Images/SubDir/" + str;
```

Comment: I tried adding the .CssClss="myclass" which I defined in the aspx file but it does nothing. Again, with the asp:Image tag it's OK. With the asp:Hyperlink tag, the images are all 100%.

Comment: in you css class please add  display:block; position:relative;

Comment: the img {
    max-width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}  works the easiest.