# Why does my image shrink way too much when I resize via CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a design involving Bootstrap's `col-xs-push` to revert the place of an image and a block of text in my design. When the user resizes the window, the image should grow smaller as not to break the design, but unfortunately any change I make to the image makes it shrink into a rather pathetic version of itself.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-6">
    <h2>Filler topic</h2>
    <h4 class="mtb">Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-pull-6 second-content">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/pMa4JM1.jpg" class="myimage">
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
@media(max-width:767px) {

.myimage {
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: auto;
}

}
```

If you take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7y0s8hj8/), you'll see the tree grow way, way smaller than it should.

It also keeps shrinking despite setting a `min-width` (which I did just to illustrate this behavior).

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its working as it should, according to the css you added:

- when the resolution is smaller than 767px, it will become 50% of its container width;
- that **min-width: 50%** is relevant to the container, so if you're container shrinks down, so will the image;

If you want the image to have a fixed min-width size, you can use **px** for that, so that it won't be relevant to its container:

```
@media(max-width:767px) {

    .myimage {
        max-width: 50%;
        max-height: auto;
        width: 50%;
        height: auto;
        min-width: 100px;/*Note the px*/
        min-height: auto;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set your `width` or `min-width` to a percentage value it will apply the percentage width as it relates to the container, not to the image itself. Therefore the image will keep getting smaller as the container keeps getting smaller.

I would suggest setting a static minimum pixel value either on the container or on your image.

Answer (score 0):

The image width is always 50% of it's div parent which itself is 50% of the window. So the image width is 25% of the window not considering the paddings and margins. I checked it in chrome developer panel and works correctly.

Another thing is when you define the width in percent it's not logical to define min-width and max-width in percent too. Actually here you don't need to define min-width and max-width.

If you want half of the image native width look at this thread:
[Display image at 50% of its "native" size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699621/display-image-at-50-of-its-native-size)

Best answer would be using javascript:

```
<img src="..." onload="this.width/=2;this.onload=null;" />
```

Comment: How do I make it 50% of itself?

Comment: @LyndonJohnson you mean 50% of the native image width?

Comment: Indeed. Guess I have to use pixel width for that?

Comment: @LyndonJohnson I edited my answer. you can use javascript. look at the thread for full discussion.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this. Just replace this css, Now image will grow depend on parent div

```css
@media(max-width:767px) {
    
.myimage {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

}
```