# Alignment issues with CSS3 transform scale

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Im trying to use css3 scale property, but im facing issues with alignment of preceding elements

I see lots of spacing created after an element is scaled using css3.

Trying to place an images and titles beside it for a list. But when image is scaled the tile is pushed down.   don't want to use absolute as it may give bad impact in different devices and page re-size

```
Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sonymax46/xhwcvmj8
```

Also can you elaborate why this is happening

Can some one help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `scale` through the `transform` property, adapt the `width` and `height` of the element to the desire size. If you don't do so, the element is going to keep the original size, resulting in that blank space.

Then you can set correctly the image size using this CSS:

```
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Here you have your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhwcvmj8/4/) updated.

Comment: yes, the normal background properties works, but im  looking for solution in transform scale.

Comment: @Sumanth: your fiddle is not available any longer and I don't remember your original code. Anyway, as _jaunt_ and I have explained, `trasform: scale(x, y)` doesn't modify the amount of space that the element takes into the page. I'm sorry to say that you are looking for a non-existing solution. Have a look to someone with a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699621/display-image-at-50-of-its-native-size).

Comment: thanks for looking into this,  after some R&D i found a way. take a look at  updated [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/sonymax46/ow4vt3oc/1/). I have used a new wrapper to image tags which is scaled using tramform scale. This new wrapper controls the actual image dimensions to avoid unnecessary spacing.

Comment: @Sumanth: I'm glad that you found a solution that makes you happy. Anyway, note that you are harcoding the dimensions of the wrapper. That means that you can not modify the `x` in `trasform: scale(x)` because the wrapper would not adapt to it. In other words, if you just hardcode the dimensions of the image you will get the same result without the scaling overhead. So I contend that a just `trasform: scale(x)` solution is, unfortunately, not possible.