# Problem displaying image at 50% of native size using onload in HTML tag

Tags: image, resize, native, resolution, onload

Trying to display images of various sizes and aspect ratios at 50% of their native sizes.

– Scaling them down beforehand isn't an option, as they look very low res on a high res monitor.

– `width: 50%` scales them down based on width of container div, not original image size, so this doesn't work.

– `transform: scale(0.5)` scales the image correctly, but parent div retains original size.

– `<img src="" onload="this.height*=0.5">` almost solves the issue for me, since this correctly scales the image AND the parent div scales down to fit it. HOWEVER, the parent div needs to have a max-width specified, which seems to be interfering with this approach. I've deduced that where an original image exceeds the width of the parent div, it is already scaled down from its original size, and the onload() function then scales down from this reduced version of the image, rather than from the original size.

See this link: https://jsfiddle.net/trf0412/m4osetd3/.

The images in this example are images of tables – all cells of all tables should be the same width and height. This is the case when the images are all full size, but note in their scaled down versions some of the tables have much smaller cells - this happens where the original sized images (4x bigger) exceeded the width of the page.

Any ideas?

Very similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699621/display-image-at-50-of-its-native-size), but I couldn't find a solution there.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a possible solution, using naturalWidth property:

```
<img src="" onload="this.width=this.naturalWidth/2">
```

This appears to avoid the issue whereby the already-scaled-down image gets scaled down even further, as it is seeing the image's native width!

It works in Firefox, Chrome and Opera, but in Safari the image height doesn't scale proportionally with the width, so this has to be defined separately.