# Scale group of svg in relation to one another

Tags: html, css, svg, scale

I have a group of svg files that represent real life products. I want to represent the products on a carousel slider, but I need the products to be sized in relation to one another. The svgs have the product's physical dimensions on the height, width, and viewbox attributes.

Is there a way to put each image in a generic container (let's say 200px by 200px) and have them scaled in relation to one another based on the height and width in the svgs? My current problem is that each svg always stretches to fit the size of the container, so you can't tell how big the products actually are relative to one another.

I put an example of what the outer wrapper on the svgs look like.

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="553.72" height="852.33" viewBox="0 0 553.72 852.33"></svg>`

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="311.4" height="587.69" viewBox="0 0 311.4 587.69">`

Here is how the html with the wrapped svgs looks

`<div style="flex-direction: row; align-items: center>"`
    `<div style="width: 150px; display: flex;>`
        `<img src="image1.svg" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;"/>`
    `</div>`
    `<div style="width: 150px; display: flex;>`
        `<img src="image2.svg" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;"/>`
    `</div>`
    `<div style="width: 150px; display: flex;>`
        `<img src="image3.svg" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;"/>`
    `</div>`
`</div>`

Comment: Could you provide an example where svg stratches to fit the size of its container? I don't observe such a behaviour.

Comment: Does my edit help at all? I'm guessing the width set to 100% on the image is part of the problem.. but if I don't set the width to anything, the images are massive and take up the whole page

Comment: So the proportions are correct without `width: 100%`. Then you just need to resize all the images to for example 10% of their original size. I suggest you try someting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699621/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397049/).